# Interactive markers not showing in RViz

Tags: ros, ros2, rviz, interactive-markers

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to display a cube interactive marker using the interactive_marker_tutorials (have to build from source). Running the cube example:

```
ros2 run interactive_marker_tutorials cube
```

Then, running rviz:

```
rviz2
```

Add an interactive marker display with namespace set to `cube`, and RViz spams the following and the interactive marker doesn't show:

```
[INFO] [1657456819.061519998] [rviz]: Sending request for interactive markers
[INFO] [1657456819.093636879] [rviz]: Service response received for initialization
[INFO] [1657456819.124743724] [rviz]: Sending request for interactive markers
[INFO] [1657456819.158057054] [rviz]: Service response received for initialization
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/403587/interactive-markers-not-showing-in-rviz/) by [ijnek](https://answers.ros.org/users/73298/ijnek/) on ROS Answers with karma: 460 on 2022-07-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The issue is due to no TF data to transform the interactive marker's in the `base_link` frame to the `map` frame RViz is trying to display.

Simply change the Fixed Frame to `base_link` in RViz:

[image: image description]

---

Originally posted by [ijnek](https://answers.ros.org/users/73298/ijnek/) with karma: 460 on 2022-07-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0